# How to render portable block from sanity in vue app

Tags: vue.js, sanity

I'm testing around with sanity right now and I am trying to display portable text of sanity on my vue frontend. Sadly it does not work as expected.

So i use the npm package `sanity-blocks-vue-component` to render the portable text and the normal fetch function which is privided in the docs of sanity.

This is my file where I fetch it successfully but the SanityBlock does nothing:

```js
<template>
    <div :class="name">
        <SanityBlocks :block="content.impressumContent" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { SanityBlocks } from 'sanity-blocks-vue-component';
    import sanity from "../../sanity.js";

    const query = `*[_type == "impressum"]{
        impressumContent,
    }
    `
    export default {
        components: { 
            SanityBlocks 
        },
        data() {
            return {
                name: 'p-impressum',
                loading: true,
                content: [],
                }
            },
        created() {
            this.fetchData();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchData() {
                this.error = this.impressum = null;
                this.loading = true;
                sanity.fetch(query).then(
                    (content) => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.content = content;
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        this.error = error;
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And that's the scheme that I fetch:

```js
export default {
    name: 'impressum',
    type: 'document',
    title: 'Impressum',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'impressumContent',
            title: 'Impressum Content',
            type: 'array',
            of: [
                {
                    type: 'block'
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't get my head around why this isn't working. Hopefully somone can help me.

Thaanks:))